# Sequelize duplicate Users on scoreboard

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a User table, and a Score table. Users can have multiple scores. I want to render a scoreboard, and I want it to render the top Scores with the User associated. Right now, it does do that, but duplicate Users will appear. e.g. One user has 3 very high scores, so they are appearing at the top of the leaderboard 3 times. How would I go about filtering out the Scores that have duplicate Users associated?

Here is what I have so far. I can't find if there's a way to use Sequelize to do what I want it to do, or if there's a way to filter the data.

```
router.get('/leaderboard', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        //get all score data, include username associated, and sort by descending
        const scoreDataRaw = await Score.findAll({
            include: [
                {
                    model: User,
                    attributes: ['username']
                }
            ],
            order: [
                ['score', 'ASC']
            ]
        })
        //clean data
        const scoreData = scoreDataRaw.map((score) => score.get({ plain: true }))

        res.render('leaderboard', { scoreData })
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json(error);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//add distinct:true while doing findAll query to avoid duplicates

router.get('/leaderboard', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        //get all score data, include username associated, and sort by descending
        const scoreDataRaw = await Score.findAll({
            distinct:true,
            include: [
                {
                    model: User,
                    attributes: ['username']
                }
            ],
            order: [
                ['score', 'ASC']
            ]
        })
        //clean data
        const scoreData = scoreDataRaw.map((score) => score.get({ plain: true }))

        res.render('leaderboard', { scoreData })
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json(error);
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work, I think it's getting distinct scores, but not distinct users.